# What is the difference between getExtras and getBundleExtras?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Could someone please explain to me what is the difference between `getExtras()` and `getBundleExtras()`?

Answer (score 19):

`getBundleExtra("String")` gets a bundle named `String`.

`getExtras()` gets a bundle with all of the items placed into the array.

A bundle can be placed using a `putExtra(Bundle, String tag)` command, so the `getBundleExtra()` will return that value.

Comment: @Binngokute: I see you are fairly new, so let me just explain a few things. If you find a question or an answer helpful, there are a few ways to give back to the user. One of them is to upvote the answer, and a second way is to select one of the answers as the one that you accept. I see you haven't accepted any answers yet, and people are generally more helpful to people who have accepted answers. Just a tip for the future.

Answer (score 11):

Worth notting is the fact that `getExtras()` returns **copy** of the all items placed in the intent, its implementation looks like this:

```
4433    public Bundle getExtras() {
4434        return (mExtras != null)
4435                ? new Bundle(mExtras)
4436                : null;
4437    }
```

so its not a good idea to call `intent.getExtras().putInt(...)`

Comment: Upvoting this - I just wasted over an hour because I didn't realise that getExtras doesn't actually return the original Bundle.